# Finishing the proof for finding eigenvectors of a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

I have the following problem: I have a circulating matrix $$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0     & c_{n-1} & \dots  & c_{2} & c_{1}  \\
c_{1} & c_0    & c_{n-1} &         & c_{2}  \\
\vdots  & c_{1}& c_0    & \ddots  & \vdots   \\
c_{n-2}  &        & \ddots & \ddots  & c_{n-1}   \\
c_{n-1}  & c_{n-2} & \dots  & c_{1} & c_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and I am trying to find bases for the Eigenspaces of $C$.

I have already shown several things: For a matrix $A$ with $$ \quad A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & \dots & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
 \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$$

I have shown that the eigenvalues $t_j$ of $A$ are $t,t^2,t^3, \dots , t^n$ with $t= e^{i\phi}, \ \phi = \frac{2\pi}{n}$. I have also found that the eigenvectors of $A$ must then be: $(1,t^k,t^{2k},...,t^{(n-1)k}), k\in \{1,...,n\}$
.

Now I know that I can write $C$ as a linear combination of $A$, such that $$C = c_0+c_1A+...+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}$$

Let $Q(A)$ denote this polynomial. I have also shown that I can write $Q(A)=\sum_{j=1}^nQ(t_j)p_j$ whereas $t_j$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$ and $p_j$ denote the orthogonal projection onto the $j$-th canonical basis vector.

Therefore I know that the eigenvalues of $C$ must be $Q(t_j)$, i.e $\lambda_j=  c_0+c_1t_j+...c_{n-1}t_j^{n-1}$

Now I am stuck however. I am trying to find a basis for the eigenspaces of $C$, which should be easily doable using what I have already shown, but I am not quite sure what I could do.

Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $v_j$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $t_j$, then it is also an eigenvector of $Q(A)$ associated with $Q(t_j)$.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks once again for the help, I do really appreciate it.